# Navigate to a certain tab and close that tab in OSX Terminal

Tags: terminal, tabs

I've got multiple terminal tabs open, and I want to be able to close the current tab. How can I make the current terminal tab be the active tab, so that I can close that tab with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>?

I am in the default Mac terminal.

Answer (score 5):

In OSX Terminal, hold down the keys <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> while arrowing right or left. This will allow you to switch between active tabs.

When on the tab you wish to close, as you noted, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> will close that tab.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to do it in a script, you might use something like this:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    repeat with w in (get windows)
        repeat with t in (get tabs of w)
            if processes of t contains "man" then
                set selected of t to true
                set index of w to 1
            end if
            --properties of t
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal"
    perform action "AXRaise" of window 1
    tell menu 3 of menu bar 1
        if enabled of menu item "Close Tab" then
            click menu item "Close Tab"
        else
            click menu item "Close Window"
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```

Tab objects don't have a `close` command. `set index to 1` doesn't actually raise a window, but it makes it it appear as window 1 to System Events, which supports the AXRaise action.